# match a paragraph starts with some letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that contains paragraphs starting with AB, I wanted to get all these paragraphs, 
I used the following code, but it returns nothing:

```
import re
paragraphs = re.findall(r'AB[.\n]+AD',text) #AD is the beginning of the next paragraph
```

Any idea why did not this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
re.findall(r'AB.+?(?=AD)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

The `re.DOTALL` flag will let the dot cover everything included the newlines. And `(?=AD)` will match everything up to the last character before `AD`, but will not include `AD` into the matched string.

You can then `rstrip()` the resulting strings to remove all newlines from the end.

Answer (score 0):

from the python `re` module documentation:

```
[] 
    Used to indicate a set of characters. Characters can be listed individually, 
    or a range of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and 
    separating them by a '-'. Special characters are not active inside sets.
```

this means that `.` inside the brackets matches a dot, and not any character as it would anywhere else in a regexp.